# Creating an overall Rating or Number based on meeting number of criteria? Higher number of criteria create green gradient

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to generate a rating of number on my pine script that reviews a set number of criteria and generates a rating based on the baseline and being above vs below it. Then translating that number or rating to select a green to red gradient color on the bar.

I have looked at different cascading criteria and individual criteria being met outputs a color.

I would like the script to determine a rating for a stock based on the criteria I set and then output a gradient from red to green on how high that number is. A great buy will show bright green, neutral will be yellow and sell/avoid will be red.

Here is a similar code that uses the concept.

```
`//@version=3
 study(title="Collar Color Indicator", shorttitle="COLLAR")

//RSI
src = close, len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
up = sma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = sma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))

// MACD
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACDLine = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
MACDSignal = ema(MACDLine, MACDLength)
MACD = MACDLine - MACDSignal

// COLLAR SIGNAL DETERMINATION AND PLOT
ema5=ema(close,5)
ema20=ema(close,20)

score = 0
score1 = 0
score2 = 0
score3 = 0
score0 = 0

if ema5 > ema20  
score := score +1 
if MACD >0
score := score +1 
if rsi >50
score := score +1 

plot(iff(score==3,1,0), color=green, linewidth=2, style=columns)
plot(iff(score==2,1,0), color=yellow, linewidth=2, style=columns)
plot(iff(score==1,1,0), color=orange, linewidth=2, style=columns)
plot(iff(score==0,1,0), color=red, linewidth=2, style=columns)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got you correctly, but here a snippet, which draws candles based with colors picked based on several conditions:

```
//@version=3
study("My Script")

BRIGHT_GREEN = #7CFC00  // hex color. For more gradient could be used more colors

getColor(num_criteria) =>
  num_criteria >= 4 ? BRIGHT_GREEN :
  num_criteria >= 3 ? green :
  num_criteria > 1 ? yellow :
  red


num_true_criteria = 0

if open > open[1]
    num_true_criteria := num_true_criteria + 1

if high > sma(low, 4)
    num_true_criteria := num_true_criteria + 1

if high[1] - low[1] > 100
    num_true_criteria := num_true_criteria + 1

if n % 2 == 0
    num_true_criteria := num_true_criteria + 1


plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=getColor(num_true_criteria))
```

I hope, it'll be helpful for you.

Comment: Let me give it a try but it looks to be exactly what I was trying to do. I found this script with a similar coding, but yours is easier.